# setting up PHP 5.6.3 to work with IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, php

First time asking a question so please bear with me. I don't spend a lot of time using IIS but decided to dip a toe in the pond. I have a server that is no longer in production but is still good enough so I thought I would turn it into a ticketing server. I wanted a free ticketing system that has the ability to pull from LDAP. I read good things about OSTicket so I thought I would give it a whirl.

I have IIS 8 working with PHP 7.1.1 nts x64, php manager, and MySQL 5.7 on this windows 2012 server. I was able to create the new site and was able to load the new site and get through the basic config but then I can't log in to the system. I read some posts that indicate that OSTicket 1.10 doesn't yet work with PHP 7.1.1 and that downgrading to 5.6.3 is the solution. I then attempted to install php 5.6.3 but can't get it to work (I get 500 errors). I've installed both the x86 stable version and the x64 experimental version. Same issue with both. Rebooting hasn't helped. Stopping and starting the site hasn't helped. Can anyone help me understand what might be wrong? Here are the basics of what I did to get it setup:

For x86 version:
I created the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6
I copied the contents of the PHP installer into that folder
I copied php.ini-production to php.ini
I added the path to the path system variable
In IIS I added the application to the FastCGI settings to match the one for 7.1.1
In IIS I added the module mapping to match the one for 7.1.1

when I use PHP Manager in IIS to change to 5.6.3 and then tell it to check phpinfo() I get the 500 error whereas when set to 7.1.1 no error and I get the phpinfo printout. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is the log output:

> - System
>
>   - Provider
>
>   [ Name]  Application Error
>
>   - EventID 1000
>
>   [ Qualifiers]  0 
>      Level 2 
>      Task 100 
>      Keywords 0x80000000000000
>
>   - TimeCreated
>
>   [ SystemTime]  2017-02-13T14:53:42.000000000Z 
>      EventRecordID 15667 
>      Channel Application 
>      Computer SAS2K10.sands.lan 
>      Security
> - EventData
>
>   php-cgi.exe 
>     5.6.30.0     58803748     MSVCR110.dll 
>     6.2.9200.21941     5792e533     c0000135     000683ba     cd4     01d28608f81651f3     C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\php-cgi.exe
>     MSVCR110.dll     35d5e51a-f1fc-11e6-93ee-984be16edd6e

Comment: A 500 error is the webservers way of saying "I have a major problem, but I don't want to talk about it in public". Look at the error log of the server, there will be a clear message saying what's wrong.

Comment: Also note that IIS has the default setting to give clear error messages directly when calling it from localhost.

Comment: Please edit additions directly into your question, don't add them as comments. They are unreadable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to installed the [MS V C++ redistributable that contained MSVCR110.dll](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679). Problem solved! Thanks Gerald Schneider for helping me get there on my own. Lesson learned that checking the logs is crucial!